# How to deploy on minikube from Gitlab and Helm

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, gitlab-ci, helm3

I'm trying to deploy a java spring project on my local minikube using gitlab-ci pipeline.. but I keep getting

`ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: setting up credentials: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:maverick:default" cannot create resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "maverick". Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information`

I've installed gitlab-runner on the "maverick" namespace

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: gitlab-runner
  namespace: maverick
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: gitlab-runner
  namespace: maverick
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods"]
    verbs: ["list", "get", "watch", "create", "delete"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/exec"]
    verbs: ["create"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/log"]
    verbs: ["get"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/attach"]
    verbs: ["list", "get", "create", "delete", "update"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["secrets"]
    verbs: ["list", "get", "create", "delete", "update"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["configmaps"]
    verbs: ["list", "get", "watch", "create", "delete"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: gitlab-runner
  namespace: maverick
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: maverick
subjects:
- namespace: maverick
  kind: ServiceAccount
  name: gitlab-runner
```

and the values

```
gitlabUrl: https://gitlab.com/
runnerRegistrationToken: ".... my token .... "

runners:
  privileged: false
  tags: k8s
  serviceAccountName: gitlab-runner
```

My gitlab-ci.yml is like this:

```
docker-build-job:
  stage: docker-build
  image: $MAVEN_IMAGE
  script:
    - mvn jib:build -Djib.to.image=${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest -Djib.to.auth.username=${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -Djib.to.auth.password=${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}

deploy-job:
  image: alpine/helm:3.2.1
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - k8s
  script:
    - helm upgrade ${APP_NAME} ./charts --install --values=./charts/values.yaml --namespace ${APP_NAME}
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'master'
      when: always
```

And the chart folder has the deployment.yaml like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: maverick
  namespace: maverick
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: maverick
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: maverick
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: maverick
          image: registry.gitlab.com/gfalco77/maverick:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8001
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-credentials
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: maverick
spec:
  ports:
    - name: maverick
      port: 8001
      targetPort: 8001
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: maverick
```

There's also a registry-credentials which I created according to https://chris-vermeulen.com/using-gitlab-registry-with-kubernetes/ and they are installed in the maverick namespace

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: registry-credentials
  namespace: maverick
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: .. base64 creds ..
```

I can see the gitlab-runner has the permissions on apigroup "" for create.. but still it seems it can't download the image from the registry maybe, not sure what is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I’m confused - by “local” do you mean the minikube deployment is running on your laptop/desktop, and not a server? This looks like GitLab isn’t able to authenticate with the host, which would totally make sense - GitLab can’t deploy something onto your laptop. Maybe I’m missing something or you’ve excluded a bunch of configuration from the build?

Comment: Or is GitLab runner installed inside the same minikube deployment?

Comment: yes it's my local minikube on my laptop .. Gitlab-runner is installed on the maverick namespace and it's visible in Gitlab.com, so I thought it would be able to deploy on local !? Unless this is impossible, then how can I do that?

Comment: I mean when I run minikube start on my laptop I can see in Settings/Runners the registered gitlab-runner which is installed on minikube. I thought it should be able to pull the image from the container registry, or not!?

Comment: if I run kubectl auth can-i get secret -n maverick --as=system:serviceaccount:maverick:default I get a NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved adding the following ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding, especially the second one with name "default"
After this the job in gitlab continues and then tries to use the user `system:serviceaccount:maverick:gitlab-runner` , but it fails on something else I need to figure out

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: cluster-admin
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods"]
    verbs: ["list", "get", "watch", "create", "delete"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/exec"]
    verbs: ["create"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/log"]
    verbs: ["get"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/attach"]
    verbs: ["list", "get", "create", "delete", "update"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["secrets"]
    verbs: ["list", "watch", "get", "create", "delete", "update"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["configmaps"]
    verbs: ["list", "get", "watch", "create", "delete", "update"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cluster-admin-role
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: gitlab-runner
    namespace: maverick
roleRef: # referring to your ClusterRole
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cluster-admin-role
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: maverick
```